# Why are my Uinput gamepad events not working?

Tags: kernel, openrc

I have a problem from Artix Linux: I want to connect my Wii Remote to use it as a Gamepad, it does not want to work because the uinput module does not want to interpret the events associated with Gamepad Inputs, it does not catch for example "BTN_A" or others, but if I put another as "KEY_A" if it recognizes it but acts as a keyboard input in that case. What solution do you propose?

Note that I use WMinput, and I have already installed cwiid, wminput, and even fixed the uinput module in the kernel.